# How to match urls not inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, url

This is similar to this [regex match keywords that are not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620250/regex-match-keywords-that-are-not-in-quotes) but in javascript, I have regex like this:

```
/(https?:((?!&[^;]+;)[^\s:"'<)])+)/
```

and need to replace all urls by a tags but not when they are inside quotes, How can I do this?

Comment: [Match urls but not inside brakets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447284/match-urls-but-not-inside-brakets) - Is it the same or is it different? Why do you ask 2 questions on the same thing?

Comment: @Antony because I realize that I don't need brakets anymore, since in the place in my code brakets are replaced, I remove the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same solution as proposed in the referred topic.

Code snippet in JavaScript:

```
var text = 'Hello this text is an <tagToReplace> example. bla bla bla "this text is inside <tagNotToReplace> a string" "random string" more text bla bla bla "foo"';

var patt1=/<[^>]*>(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)/g;
text.match(patt1);
// output: ["<tagToReplace>"]

text.replace(patt1, '<newTag>');
// output: "Hello this text is an <newTag> example. bla bla bla "this text is inside <tagNotToReplace> a string" "random string" more text bla bla bla "foo""
```

Explanation of the pattern is the same as proposed [F.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620387/1554314):

> ```
> text            # match the literal characters 'text'
> (?=             # start lookahead
>    [^"]*          # match any number of non-quote characters
>    (?:            # start non-capturing group, repeated zero or more times
>       "[^"]*"       # one quoted portion of text
>       [^"]*         # any number of non-quote characters
>    )*             # end non-capturing group
>    $              # match end of the string
> )              # end lookahead
> ```