# Regex (PHP) Remove all horizontal whitespace except between quotes ("" and '') (include escaped quotes)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, removing-whitespace

Using preg_replace (PHP) I want to remove all horizontal whitespace except for the whitespace found between quotes ("" and '') (including escaped quotes)

An example (regex should turn left side in right side):

```
2 + 2                    => 2+2
f( " ")                  => f(" ")
f("Test \"mystring\" .") => f("Test \"mystring\" .")
f("' ",   " ")           => f("' "," ")
```

Using [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620387/9256034) I came up with:
`\h(?=[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*$)(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`

Which basically looks ahead and checks if there are an even amount of quotes until the end of the string (both "" and '').

However, I have problems with escaped characters and quotes inside quotes.

```
" ' test "  => The ' causes problem
" \" test " => The \" causes problem
```

I have thought of using negative lookbehinds: `(?<!\\)"` but can't get it to work. The next regex fails. It doesn't match when a string contains escaped quotes.

```
\h(?=[^"]*(?:(?<!\\)"(?:[^"]*?(?<!\\)")[^"]*?)*$)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*(?:"[^\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\')(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKR5YG/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)` - a `'...'` or `"...."`  substring where the first quotation mark is not itself escaped, which is skipped once matched (so, nothing inside them gets removed)

  - `(?<!\\)` - no `\` char allowed immediately to the left of the current location
  - `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more repetitions of double backslashes
  - `(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')` - either of the two alternatives:

    - `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - a string literal inside double quotation marks
    - `"` - a double quote
    - `[^\\"]*` - 0 or more chars other than `\` and `"`
    - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - zero or more repetitions of a `\` followed with any char (`\\.`) and then any 0 or more chars other than `"` and `\` (`[^"\\]*`)
    - `|` - or
    - `'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - a string literal inside single quotation marks
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs that omit the found match and make the regex engine go on searching for a next match starting at the current regex index
- `|\h+` - or 1 or more horizontal whitespaces

[**PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/NhcMo):

```
$strs = ['2 + 2', 'f( " ")', 'f("Test \\"mystring\\" .")', 'f("\' ",   " ")'];
$rx = '~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*(?:"[^\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\')(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+~s';
print_r( preg_replace($rx, '', $strs) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2+2
    [1] => f(" ")
    [2] => f("Test \"mystring\" .")
    [3] => f("' "," ")
)
```