# Regex to detect words that are not quoted

Tags: python, regex, quotes

I have this regex which detects all words:

`\b[^\d\W]+\b`

And I have this regex to detect quoted texts:

`\'[^\".]*?\'|\"[^\'.]*?\"`

Is there a regex which can detect words which are not in quotes(both single and double)?

example:

```py
import re
a = "big mouse eats cheese? \"non-detected string\" 'non-detected string too' hello guys"
re.findall(some_regex, a)
```

It should output this
`['big', 'mouse', 'eats', 'cheese', 'hello', 'guys']`

I know I can use `re.sub()` to detect the quoted text and then replace it with a blank string but thats what I don't want to do.

I also looked up this page [regex match keywords that are not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620250/regex-match-keywords-that-are-not-in-quotes) and tried this `(^([^"]|"[^"]*")*)|(^([^']|'[^']*')*)` but it didn't work [A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324749/a-regex-to-detect-string-not-enclosed-in-double-quotes) also tried this `(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])|(?<![\S'])([^'\s]+)(?![\S'])` both detected all words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
a = '''big mouse eats cheese? "non-detected string" 'non-detected string too' hello guys'''
print( [x for x in re.findall(r'''"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\b([^\d\W]+)\b''', a) if x])
# => ['big', 'mouse', 'eats', 'cheese', 'hello', 'guys']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gVAVlY). The list comprehension is used to post-process the output to remove empty items that result from matching the quoted substrings.

This approach works because [`re.findall` only returns the captured substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird) when the capturing group is defined in the regex. `"[^"]*"|'[^']*'` part matches but does not capture strings between single and double quotes, and the `\b([^\d\W]+)\b` part matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more letters or underscores in between word boundaries.

Comment: so if i try doing `re.compile().search()` will it work? as you said it works because re.findall() behaves weird

Comment: @Good To get the first match only, use `re.search`, but you need to check if there is a match first, and then access `match.group(1)` value. However, with this approach, you need to use `re.findall` to get all matches as `re.search` might yield an empty match. So, get all matches using the suggested approach and then use indexing to get the first non-empty match if necessary.